# Flash memory search string

Tags: c, search, flash-memory

Flash memory is used for logging frame: $D data, $E error and $R report and few more. Each frame has timestamp after the frame type: $D,Timestamp.........$E. All data in Hex and variable length, ie 0 = 0, 1587912486= 5EA59F26, it is not fix length frame. The timestamp is UDT1970.

NB: In Flash, each page is 256 Byte.

So far I start at the center page between start and end page where on that page it seeks (via $D match) and read timestamp (read flash byte by byte into array until ',' is detected) at the start of each page. if the timestamp is less or more than target timestamp, it jumps of next half page number (Step) and repeats until step goes to 1. I then take one page back and perform byte by byte search for timestamp upward until actual match is found. This is two process: Page jump search and then byte by byte search.

I'm curious if there a similar algorithm under a specific name or better algorithm optimized for Flash memory search. NB: I have a constraint in SRAM use, ie transferring to large buffer is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you start off running a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) until you find the interval containing your key, and then run a [linear search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search) within that interval.

If your sample rate is more or less constant, you may be able to zero in on the correct interval faster with [interpolation search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search), but it's very sensitive to the accuracy of your interpolation, which will depend on the uniformity of your sampling.

The most obvious obstacle to rapid searching (and accurate interpolation) is the variable frame size: if you can either fix the size without wasting too much space, or write a separate index (itself with fixed-size records, whether it's a small one to fit in SRAM, or it also lives in flash), it should be easier.

For example, you could keep a rapidly-searchable index storing timestamp+index (just an array for binary or interpolation search again, or a tree or skip list, or something else). Then you have a quick lookup with fixed offsets, and an indirection to the variable-sized data.